# how to make Gmail Chat Bot, a simple one?

Tags: gmail, chat, bots

I want to make a gmail chat bot. i dont know anything abt it. What language, what software to use? Can google app engine and eclipse be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this two links out it will surely help you out http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp and http://blog.appenginefan.com/2009/09/my-first-attempt-at-xmpp-in-java-app.html