# How to build gmail chat bot?

Tags: chat, bots, google-talk, chatbot

I want to build an simple gmail chat bot. 
The bot reads the chat messsage of the recipient and responds it..

I have developed the logic for response to the message
but now im stuck with the bot configuration.

How to setup a gmail bot which can receive the message from chat window and give the message to me . and reply my message back to the person in chat ?

note: this question may seem duplicate but i have tried every solution to previous question i am unable to find a complete solution from scratch anywhere.

Hope any when can help me here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make Gmail Chat Bot, a simple one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307927/how-to-make-gmail-chat-bot-a-simple-one)

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the Google Talk API. More information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/talk/). I have never used it before, but from what I read, you need to have to write your logic in a compatible language to interface with the API and build up from there. Very standard Google API docs, help, etc in the link.

If you know Python there is a [library](http://code.google.com/p/pygtalkrobot/) built for this purpose, bot allow developers to quickly and easily deploy bots. I highly recommend you use that. If you don't know Python, there is anoter guide [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tutorial-create-bot-for-gtalk-yahoo-messenger/4354/) that explains how to do it with very minimal PHP/Perl code. If you don't know PHP or Perl, there is another resource [here](http://njsbot.simonholywell.com/) that explains how to do it in Node.js. IF you don't know Javascript, [here](http://blog.appenginefan.com/2009/09/my-first-attempt-at-xmpp-in-java-app.html) is how to do it in Java.

I don't like publishing links to guides, but the API document should have been enough. These were all found with the Google search term "make a google talk bot".

Comment: Can you extend more ?
i found that jaxl and xmpp are needed to work out..
but how to do it im just not getting..

any proper guide ?